# Sum coverage for several (in my case PHP and javascript) languages in coveralls

Tags: javascript, phpunit, code-coverage, travis-ci, coveralls

Is it possible to have sum of coverage tests from PHP and Javascript
Part of .travis.yml file

```
after_success:
  - travis_retry php vendor/bin/php-coveralls -v
  - COVERALLS_REPO_TOKEN=$coveralls_repo_token yarn coveralls
```

In this case I see only Javascript coverage.
If I remove last line or change it with previous line I'll see coverage for PHP.

But I need both coverage (PHP and Javascript) in coveralls.

Comment: I can't speak to combined coverage using "coveralls".  But this Software Recommendations answers discusses (our) tools for collecting test coverage data across multiple languages and providing combined ("sum") coverage for all of them:  https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/31786/101